# How to recover stdin overwritten by dup2?

Tags: c, unix, file-descriptor, dup2

I am trying to replace stdin with another pipe, then place the original stdin back to fd #0.

e.g.

```
dup2(p, 0); // p is a pre-existing fd of a pipe
exec(/* some commands */);

//what will be here in order to have the original stdin back?

scanf(...) //continue processing with original stdin.
```

Comment: Simply `dup2()` stdin to a temporary filedescriptor first and `dup2()` it back again later

Comment: @Ctx Is it possible to keep stdin without temporary duplicate it?

Comment: Not "keep" it, you could reopen it if it is possible. Depending on what your stdin is, this might be not possible however.

Comment: The 'exec..()` commands do not return, unless they failed.  So the only reasonable statements after an exec command are: `perror( "exec.. failed" );` followed by  `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't recover the original once it has been overwritten (closed).  What you can do is save a copy of it before you overwrite it (which requires planning ahead, of course):

```
int old_stdin = dup(STDIN_FILENO);

dup2(p, STDIN_FILENO);
close(p);               // Usually correct when you dup to a standard I/O file descriptor.

…code using stdin…

dup2(old_stdin, STDIN_FILENO);
close(old_stdin);       // Probably correct
scanf(…);
```

However, your code mentions `exec(…some commands…);` — if that is one of the POSIX [`execve()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html) family of functions, then you won't reach the `scanf()` (or the second `dup2()`) call unless the `exec*()` call fails.

Comment: Without duplicate the stdin to temporary fd, would you be able to reopen stdin?

Comment: In general, no.  The original standard input might be a pipe, a socket, or some other fancy and ephemeral file type, which cannot be reopened.  Plus you don't have a name to (re)open it with.  After the `dup2(p, STDIN_FILENO);` operation succeeds, `/dev/stdin` is no help; it yields the file that `p` was opened for, not the original standard input.

Comment: Also, while I think about it, note that you may run into problems with buffering of input if you dink with file descriptor while the standard I/O library has some input read from the kernel but not delivered to the application.  (Similar problems could occur with outputs too.)