# C redirecting STDIN not working using dup2

Tags: c, redirect, input, fork, parent-child

I'm making a simple shell and when I pass a command such as "ls > junk.txt" I want the child process to take the contents of ls and write them to junk.txt. When I do this currently a file named junk.txt is created and "junk.txt" is written to the file. Why are the contents of ls not being written instead? Am I using dup2 wrong?

The argv array contains the full command written to the shell. the argvSec should contain all the commands also excluding "<" or ">".

```
                int childExitMethod;
                pid_t spwanPID = fork();

                switch (spwanPID){
                case -1:
                    last_exit_status = 1;
                case 0:
                    token = strtok(command, " "); // Split the command into tokens
                    while (token != NULL) {//add in all tokens into arr
                        argv[i] = token;
                        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                        i++;
                    }
                    argv[i] = NULL;

                    char* redirect_arg = NULL;
                    for (int i = 0; argv[i] != NULL; i++) {//Check if array contains any redirection
                        if (strcmp(argv[i], ">") == 0) {
                            redirect_arg = argv[i + 1];
                        } else {
                            argvSec[i2] = argv[i];
                            i2++;
                        }
                    }
                    argvSec[i2] = NULL;

                    if (redirect_arg != NULL) {
                        int fd_out = open(redirect_arg, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
                        if (fd_out == -1) {
                            last_exit_status = 1;
                            exit(1);
                        }
                        dup2(fd_out, STDOUT_FILENO);    //redirect output
                        close(fd_out);

                        execvp(argvSec[0], argvSec);
                    } else {
                        execvp(argv[0], argv);
                        last_exit_status = 1;
                        exit(1);
                    }
                default:
                    waitpid(spwanPID, &childExitMethod, 0); // Wait for the child
                }
```

Comment: Is the answer for this question useful for your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924800/how-to-recover-stdin-overwritten-by-dup2 ?

Comment: @CemPolat not really I'm already doing whats in that solution.

Comment: You're not including the `>` into the arguments you're passing to the exec'ed command, but you *are* passing the filename being redirected into. So it's running `ls junk.txt`

Comment: @Shawn so should I also remove junk.txt? Including the ">" causes an error to print out that ">" isnt a command. Also in my case I have to manually redirect the output.

Comment: @Shawn thanks for the comment, removing junk.txt and only running ls works.